# UICollectionView Cell dynamic height

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have created an `UICollectionView` cell and it's displaying perfectly, but my doubt is have given an constant size of cell in `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`. My issue is each and every cell is containing dynamic height, how can i calculate and give at `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31604233/312594

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the function like so:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
       NSString* blogEntry = (NSString*)self.entries[indexPath.item];
       CGSize size = [blogEntry sizeWithAttributes:
                                @{NSFontAttributeName:font}];
       return HEADER_HEIGHT + size.height;
   }
```

Inside you want to calculate the size of the cell. One common scenario is a cell that has a header and a body of text (like a post in a blog). In this case you need to calculate the text using sizeWithAttributes: method and add the standard header size.