# How make a collectionViewCell auto size only by height?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I use feature of autosizing flow layout of collectionView

```
self.flow = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
self.flow.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
self.flow.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
self.flow.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(320, 48);
```

I want to cells will fill by width full width of CollectionView (widthCell=widthCollectionView)

But i got what autosizing work for whole size. I try playing with Content Compression/Hugging Priority - not effect.

With width of CollectionView equals 320px, i got cell size for label content size.

My cell looks like
[image]

Constraints Horizontal : H:|-8-[img(48)]-8-[label]-8-|

How to make autosize work only for Vertical but not for Horizontal?

Comment: i have answered it, works well http://stackoverflow.com/a/31604233/3382056

Comment: Mihawk, it's not a autosize example. This example i use too, but i wonder autosize.

Comment: this solution is for autolayout

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found a solution.

CollectionViewCell has a delegate [preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionReusableView_class/index.html)

So, this function gives you layoutAttributes sets as [estimatedItemSize](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/)

You need do next (for Height)

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributes {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attr = [super preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes:layoutAttributes]; //Must be called
    CGRect frame = attr.frame;
    frame.size.width = layoutAttributes.size.width; //Key here
    attr.frame = frame;
    return attr;
}
```

Same you can do to prefer size, width so make constant height (frame.size.height = layoutAttributes.size.height).

**If you just copy layoutAttributes and change width, will no effect!**

You must call super.

Comment: Saved my day! Thanks!

Comment: How do you use it? Where do you set that delegate?

Answer (score 3):

Actually you are right here is the problem with the constraints priority.

To resolve the priority constraint issue you should update the `imageView Leading priority` `999` and also `label Trailing` priority `999` either programmatically or directly from InterFace Builder.

Update priority programmatically by using the [`KVConstraintExtensionsMaster`](https://github.com/keshavvishwkarma/KVConstraintExtensionsMaster) that I have implemented to update any constraint without `IBOutlet reference` of Autolayout constraint.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell1" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.imageView changeAppliedConstraintPriority:999 forAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading];
    [cell.label changeAppliedConstraintPriority:999 forAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing];

    return cell;
}
```

After this Now you need to calculate the only height of the cell

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     CGFloat width  = CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.bounds);
     CGFloat height  =  /* do here some calculation for height */
     return CGSizeMake(width, height);;
}
```

Comment: U use sizeForItemAtIndexPath, but autoSize it's without manual calculation.

Comment: of course autoSize for both width as well as for height and but you want to cells will fill by width full width of CollectionView (widthCell=widthCollectionView). So here cell width always equals to collectionView width.

Answer (score -1):

[Dmitry Nelepov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/849961/dmitry-nelepov)'s solution in swift.

**Swift 4**

```
override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
    let attr = super.preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(layoutAttributes)
    var frame = attr.frame
    frame.size.width = layoutAttributes.size.width //Key here
    attr.frame = frame
    return attr
}
```